# Android Get contact name from phone number

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to get details about contact using phone number everything works perfect, but when the contact number is saved with some special characters then i unable to get the contact details below is my code:

```
//function called 
getContactName("+11234567890");
```

and the same number saved in contact as (+1(123)456-789)

```
//function 
public String getContactName(String number) {
    String name;
  if(number != null && !number.equals("")){
    // define the columns I want the query to return
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

    // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

    // query time
    Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        } 
        cursor.close();
    }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the bellow function to get the name from phone number. I have tested it recently. It works fine. because phone lookup will replace all special character from phone number.

ex- I saved new number 0+0141(12-23) with name Gaurav. And I call the function getContactName(01411223) then it will returns the name Gauav.

Please use following function and let me know if it does not work.

```
 public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
```

Comment: the problem is special characters are saved in my contacts

Comment: when you are reading contacts from phone that time you can call unaccent(String s) function to replace special character in name or phone number.

Comment: can u please provide me an example

Comment: @AnkitaBansal Please check my updated post. I think It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can **delete all non digit chars** from the string with `replaceAll("\\D+","");`, have a look and let me know if it works!

```
public String getContactName(String number) {
  number = number.replaceAll("\\D+","");
  String name;
  if(number != null && !number.equals("")){
    // define the columns I want the query to return
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

    // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

    // query time
    Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        } 
        cursor.close();
    }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: my number is fine but the number saved in my contact it contain special characters

Answer (score 0):

may be this code will helps

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

}
}